# php multidimensional array path segment combination loop

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

I am trying to figure a way to get this to work. But I have a hard time thinking out the logics.

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => news
            [1] => {section}
            [2] => {slug}
            [3] => {*}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => {id}
            [1] => {*}
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => {date}
            [1] => 25-07-1982
            [2] => {section}
            [3] => {slug}
            [4] => {*}
        )

)
```

That I need to convert to this result:

```
0 news/{id}/{date}
1 news/{id}/25-07-1982
2 news/{id}/{section}
3 news/{id}/{slug}
4 news/{id}/{*}
5 news/{*}/{date}
6 news/{*}/25-07-1982
7 news/{*}/{section}
8 news/{*}/{slug}
9 news/{*}/{*}
10 {section}/{id}/{date}
11 {section}/{id}/25-07-1982
12 {section}/{id}/{section}
13 {section}/{id}/{slug}
14 {section}/{id}/{*}
15 {section}/{*}/{date}
16 {section}/{*}/25-07-1982
17 {section}/{*}/{section}
18 {section}/{*}/{slug}
19 {section}/{*}/{*}
20 {slug}/{id}/{date}
21 {slug}/{id}/25-07-1982
22 {slug}/{id}/{section}
23 {slug}/{id}/{slug}
24 {slug}/{id}/{*}
25 {slug}/{*}/{date}
26 {slug}/{*}/25-07-1982
27 {slug}/{*}/{section}
28 {slug}/{*}/{slug}
29 {slug}/{*}/{*}
30 {*}/{id}/{date}
31 {*}/{id}/25-07-1982
32 {*}/{id}/{section}
33 {*}/{id}/{slug}
34 {*}/{id}/{*}
35 {*}/{*}/{date}
36 {*}/{*}/25-07-1982
37 {*}/{*}/{section}
38 {*}/{*}/{slug}
39 {*}/{*}/{*}
```

The input array could contain more than three keys, so the solution I'm looking for should be dynamic. And the result should have the same order as the result shown above.
Does someone know how to do this in a efficient way? Can someone give me a push in the right direction? Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Put "permutations php" to http://google.com

Comment: I think that all you need are 3 nested loops

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for that term, I was struggling to name this issue to be able to Google for it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sth like this

```
foreach ($array[0] as $val0 ) 
  foreach ($array[1] as $val1 ) 
    foreach ($array[2] as $val2 ) 
        $newArray[] = "$val0/$val1/$val2";
```

EDIT: for variable array length

```
function recursive($array , $length = 0){
  $retval =array();

  if($length < count($array) -1){
    foreach ($array[$length] as $val0 ) 
        foreach (recursive($array, $length+1) as $val1)
            $retval[] =  "$val0/$val1";
  }
  else
  {
     foreach ($array[$length] as $val0 ) 
        $retval[] =  "$val0";
  }

  return $retval;
}

print_r(recursive($array));
```

Comment: Ow that is in fact getting me there! Staring at this for an hour but couldn't see this :S. Time for weekend I think... The input array could also be more that three, but I think with some recursion I should be able to get this to work!

Comment: Hmm, I can't make this recursive. Any ideas?

Comment: I added recursive function

Answer (score 1):

Just because I like writing functions that mis/manage PHP arrays, I put this together, mainly because I was pretty sure you could avoid recursion — because the structure itself isn't recursive. *(My head seems to think that is a rule, I'm sure someone somewhere can prove it wrong)*.

```php
foreach ( array_reverse($array) as $sub ) {
  if ( isset($rem) ) {
    $ret = array();
    foreach ( $sub as $itm ) {
      foreach ( $rem as $val ) { $ret[] = "$itm/$val"; }
    }
    $rem = $ret;
  }
  else {
    $rem = $sub;
  }
}
```

The output found in `$rem` is as follows:

```php
Array (
  [0] => news/{id}/{date}
  [1] => news/{id}/25-07-1982
  [2] => news/{id}/{section}
  [3] => news/{id}/{slug}
  [4] => news/{id}/{*}
  [5] => news/{*}/{date}
  [6] => news/{*}/25-07-1982
  [7] => news/{*}/{section}
  [8] => news/{*}/{slug}
  [9] => news/{*}/{*}
  [10] => {section}/{id}/{date}
  [11] => {section}/{id}/25-07-1982
  [12] => {section}/{id}/{section}
  [13] => {section}/{id}/{slug}
  [14] => {section}/{id}/{*}
  [15] => {section}/{*}/{date}
  [16] => {section}/{*}/25-07-1982
  [17] => {section}/{*}/{section}
  [18] => {section}/{*}/{slug}
  [19] => {section}/{*}/{*}
  [20] => {slug}/{id}/{date}
  [21] => {slug}/{id}/25-07-1982
  [22] => {slug}/{id}/{section}
  [23] => {slug}/{id}/{slug}
  [24] => {slug}/{id}/{*}
  [25] => {slug}/{*}/{date}
  [26] => {slug}/{*}/25-07-1982
  [27] => {slug}/{*}/{section}
  [28] => {slug}/{*}/{slug}
  [29] => {slug}/{*}/{*}
  [30] => {*}/{id}/{date}
  [31] => {*}/{id}/25-07-1982
  [32] => {*}/{id}/{section}
  [33] => {*}/{id}/{slug}
  [34] => {*}/{id}/{*}
  [35] => {*}/{*}/{date}
  [36] => {*}/{*}/25-07-1982
  [37] => {*}/{*}/{section}
  [38] => {*}/{*}/{slug}
  [39] => {*}/{*}/{*}
)
```

Also, for those that like their arrays multidimensional, this might come in handy (although I'd hate to think what the overheads are for such a code golfed version). Just to be clear, this second example doesn't create the string list as requested by the OP, but a hierarchical array structure instead.

```php
foreach ( array_reverse($array) as $sub ) {
  $rem = isset($rem)
    ? array_combine($sub, array_fill(0, count($sub), $rem))
    : $sub
  ;
}
```

This generates (again in `$rem`):

```php
Array (
  [news] => Array (
      [{id}] => Array (
          [0] => {date}
          [1] => 25-07-1982
          [2] => {section}
          [3] => {slug}
          [4] => {*}
        )
      [{*}] => Array (
          [0] => {date}
          [1] => 25-07-1982
          [2] => {section}
          [3] => {slug}
          [4] => {*}
      )
    )

  [{section}] => Array (
      [{id}] => Array (
          [0] => {date}
          [1] => 25-07-1982
          [2] => {section}
          [3] => {slug}
          [4] => {*}
        )

... and so on
```

Now if only PHP had a `join_recursive` that included keys.
*(it would be almost pointless, save for helping with the above)*.

Comment: Oh! Great I'm only seeing this now. See if I can put this to some good use. Thanks!